# UIViews in swift

Tags: uiview, swift

All,

I have an image and then I display it on the screen and then I go to a function to blur the image. Then I run another function to add a box to it. but it doesn't show the blur and the box and this is because of the addSubView and the insertSubView - I presume. Basically I cannot put both the blur and the box on the view. If i uncomment out the addBox it doesn't show the blur. Can anyone help with my understanding of addSubView and InsertSubView (array).

Here is my code :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var Box : UIView?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        let bananaImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: "edify-backgound.png")
        var imageV : UIImageView = UIImageView(image: bananaImage)
        imageV.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, bananaImage.size.width, bananaImage.size.height)
        imageV.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(imageV)
        blur()
        //addBox(CGRectMake(200, 300, 30, 30))

    }

    func addBox(location: CGRect)
    {
        let newBox = UIView(frame: location)
        newBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.view.insertSubview(newBox, atIndex: 1)
        Box = newBox
    }

    func blur()
    {
        var blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)) as UIVisualEffectView
        blur.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(blur)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you have no way of knowing whether `addBox` is doing anything or not. Here is your code:

```
    let newBox = UIView(frame: location)
    newBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.view.insertSubview(newBox, atIndex: 1)
```

A view that consists of nothing but a clear background color is completely invisible. So you see nothing - which, as Sherlock Holmes says, is exactly what you may expect to see.

Comment: Not so bad. I wish I had a nickel for every time I've added a subview and I hadn't given it a frame! So it had zero size, so it was invisible. I've done that sooooo often, I'd be rich now...